# error in .kv file==> File "/home/pi/Desktop/ali/my9.kv"

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

My code lights up an LED.
This program works in Tkinter but it did not work when I wrote it with Kivy!!
what is the problem?

kivy.py ==>

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import requests

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my9.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

my.kv==>

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
                TheRequest = requests.get('http://192.168.43.91/on')
```

error ==> File "/home/pi/Desktop/ali/my9.kv", line 13, in 
TheRequest = requests.get('http://192.168.43.91/on')
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `import` the `requests` module in kv file. And also add the `TheRequest = requests.get('http://192.168.43.91/on')` statement under `on_release` method of the `Button`. The modified kv file would be like below:

```
#:import requests requests
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_release:
                TheRequest = requests.get('https://www.android.com/')
```